# postgres how to update append and cut string

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a table looks like below:

```
id | name  | type |                                       info             | ksid |                iv                
----+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------
  1 | local |    1 | "keyId"=>"1234", "server"=>"http://10.10.13.10/keys/" |      | 30646462653237643965373830343334
```

how to append string to info so that the info value is

`"keyId"=>"1234", "server"=>"http://10.10.13.10/keys/", "period"=>"0"`

And after the changing, how to change back to

`"keyId"=>"1234", "server"=>"http://10.10.13.10/keys/"`

Comment: Why don't use a json type for "info" column?

Comment: @MassimilianoArione it's `hstore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add value with:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET info = info || '"period"=>"0"' :: hstore WHERE id = 1;
```

and remove with:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET info = delete(info, 'period') WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: thank you, is it possible that first checkout if `period` is in `info`, so that if it's not there, append it, otherwise do nothing?

Comment: this will give you rows with attribute present: SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE attr ? 'period';